# Loading Local Java Script file

Tags: javascript, cordova

On my `index.html` I am doing the following:

```
<script  src="jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
<script  src="managment.js"></script>
<script  src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

After doing some calculation, I have the need of using a function from the **managment.js** file:

```
 $.getScript("managment.js", function(){

                            alert("Script loaded and executed.");
                            login();
                            });
            }
```

And finally the `managment.js` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function login(){
    alert("asdasdasdasdasdasd");
}
</script>
```

My issue, is that the `login()` function is never called. Actually the alert I have inside `getScript`function is not called either, but the strange thing is that if I check if the `jquery.js` file is loaded the alert is called. More, if I try to call login() without doing `getScript`nothing happens has expected. My files structure is the following:

[image]

(**note: you can see that I am using 2 `managment.js` files. I tried both approaches to see if the problem was with the path of the file.**)

What am I missing here? For relevance, I am using PhoneGap, but this isn't working on the browser as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `management.js` file should not contain the `<script type="text/javascript">` tag. It should be:

```
function login(){
    alert("asdasdasdasdasdasd");
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes it was that. As you can see from this "kind of problem" I don't have much experience in Java Script. Could you explain me why it doesn't need the `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: @JackyBoy, `.js` file is written purely for JavaScripts. And the same way, `.css` for pure CSSs. So, they don't need the `<script>` or `<style>` tags. And moreover, these tags belong to HTML and not JavaScript or CSS. They say that the enclosed stuff is not HTML and they are either JavaScript or CSS. You get it?