# how to load scripts from res: URIs referring to local files?

Tags: javascript

how to load scripts from res: URIs referring to local files in javascript?

is there are any example?

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944699/loading-local-java-script-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method for this:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

read more in [Load script](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)